# acts-as-taggable-on - How do you get Tags by Parent object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-plugins

If I have two models Buckets and Photos. Buckets has_many Photos and Photo belongs_to a Bucket. If I then added tagging to photos using the acts-as-taggable-on gem. What is the best way (idiomatic and performs well) to get a unique list of tags by Bucket? or for a single Bucket?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should meet your request

```
# in your bucket class
def tag_list
  photos.inject([]) do |tags, photo|
    # with inject syntax
    tags + photo.tags.map(&:name) # remove the maps call if you need tag objects
  end.uniq
end

def alternative_tag_list
  # this code is even simpler, return unique tags
  photos.map { |p| p.tags }.flatten.uniq
end
```

You should benchmark them. They should perform well with a few data and you can always **use memoization or cache for the result**. You can reduce the number of queries needed by fetching your bucket object including both photos and tags with includes() as in

```
@bucket = Bucket.includes(:photos).includes(:tags).find(params[:id])
```

If the benchmark is not good you should go with SQL, but then you're going to loose syntactic sugar of inject & co.

Comment: Ok. Think I get the direction your headed. +1 - Let me test this out and see if I can adapt what you wrote to the buckets#index method also.